# Service worker is caching but not fetching even though they are in the same directory with the service-worker.js

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Below is my code for my **service worker**. For the Install part it will cache my static files but the problem is during the fetch. It wont even trigger the fetch event.

I checked for in the cache storage it has the files stored

Please help. Thanks

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
  .register('/dist/js/service-worker.js')
  .then(function(registration){
   console.log('Service Worker Registered',registration);
 })
 .catch(function(err){
   console.log('Service Worker Failed to Registered',err);
 });
}

file: /dist/js/service-worker.js

var CACHE_NAME = 'ams-v2';
var urlsToCache = [
 '/dist/css/style.css',
 '//mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/styles/libs.min.css',
 '/dist/js/vendor.min.js',
 '/dist/js/coreCash.min.js',
 '/dist/js/amsv2Cash.min.js'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
 // Perform install steps
 event.waitUntil(
  caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
  .then(function(cache) {
   console.log('Opened cache');
   return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
   console.log('Service Worker Failed to Cache', err);
  })
 );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
 console.log('fetch triggered here',event);
  event.respondWith(
  caches.match(event.request)
   .then(function(response) {
    // Cache hit - return response
    if (response) {
     console.log('Service Worker hit cache', response);
     return response;
    }
    return fetch(event.request);
   })
  );
});
```

In the fetch event I even add console.log on it to see it the fetch occured but the log didnt occur. I wonder why. At first I think its in the scope. But the scope is in /dist/js/ same directory where my static files located. I really dont understand why it doesnt occur.

Comment: Did you add the fetch event to the code after the service worker was registered by the browser?

Comment: yeah.. the fetch event is already there.. but theres ni fetch event triggered or catch since it doesnt even logged the console.log. :(